# How can I detect carry and overflow

Tags: computer-architecture

What is the diffrence between a **carry** bit and *overflow*

Comment: What have you tried so far? The title contains different question from body. Reading flags is strictly programming task, so off-topic here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_register

Comment: This video solved my problem. Hopefully it does for you too: https://youtu.be/9cXe_T99nL4

Comment: you should mention the architecture you are referring to.

Comment: @RanG. If the answer depends on any particular architecture, it's hard to see it being on-topic here.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I added this comment since the word "overflow" is so overloaded, that in many places it is used to mean "carry". Hmpf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Carry is generally used for unsigned arithmetic and overflow is used for signed arithmetic.**

This unsigned 8-bit operation results in Carry, but no overflow (the sign of the result is correct):

```
0xC0 + 0xD8 = 0x98
```

If we're doing unsigned 8-bit arithmetic, that's fine and we're only interested in the carry bit in this case, which tells us that the "correct" answer is actually `0x198`.

If we look at the same operation and the same operand values, but consider that the operands are signed, we have the equivalent:

```
-0x40 + -0x28 = -0x68
```

In this case, there is also no "overflow" and the result of the arithmetic is correct.

Consider this unsigned operation, however:

```
0x70 + 0x68 = 0xD8
```

No overflow here -- and no carry. The unsigned arithmetic is simple. But now look at the operands as signed values:

```
0x70 + -0x98 = 0x28
```

The answer is obviously wrong. We have subtracted a larger number from a smaller one and ended up with a positive value. The carry is not set here, so it doesn't offer a clue of the problem. The overflow flag reveals that the "correct" signed answer is `-0x28`.

[source](http://www.piclist.com/techref/method/math/c-vs-o.htm)